# NSLocalization on xCode 4.5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, nslocalizedstring

Is there any way to use Localizable.strings with NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", @"") in xCode 4.5 for iOS6 like in older iOS5?

Here is my sample code:

In Localizable.strings

**"KEY" = "Hello World!";**

In .m script

NSString *tempString = NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", NULL);

NSLog(@"My String is: %@", tempString);

The log for iOS5.1 is: "My String is: Hello World!"

**The log for iOS6 is: "My String is: KEY"**

...I'm really going to become crazy! Where is my error?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

Their is no need to create a new project and copy, just delete the localizable files, create it once again and you will be fine.

Comment: @dman Can you please make it as answer. Its work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The localized strings in my current app still work in iO6. I typically just use NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", NULL); Are you sure yours is working properly for 5.1?

Comment: I retry now in iOS6 and iOS5.1 (in 5.1 it works, in iOS6 fail).
Here is my sample code:

In Localizable.strings
"KEY" = "Hello World!";

In .m script
NSString *tempString = NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", NULL);
NSLog(@"My String is: %@", tempString);

The log for iOS5.1 is:
My String is: Hello World!

The log for iOS6 is:
My String is: KEY


...I'm really going to become crazy! Where is my error?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at answer for post: [IOS String Localization stops working when adding additional localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828766/ios-string-localization-stops-working-when-adding-additional-localization)

It works for me. Clean build + remove from simulator (or phone) fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is:

1. restart with a new project from xCode template
2. enable Localization for at least 2 languages
3. drag inside all old files from corrupted project
4. copy the contend of old storyboards into new ones
5. do frequent snapshots just in case of necessity

I really don't know where was the problem, but now all works again well as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Change the language settings of simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a semi-colon at the end of a line in one of my string-files. The compiler didn't report it even when I cleaned the project at built it again. First after restarting XCode the error was reported and I could find it and fix it.